# How to apply mutiple labels on one conversation in Gmail using keyboard only

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, keyboard-shortcuts

I use keyboard shortcut a lot for gmail.
Always using `L` and `V` to apply label and move conversation.
However, I can only apply one label at a time using shortcut `L`. I am wondering if there is sommthing like `AND` operator, so i can apply multiple labels at once using only KEYBOARD.